# GCM push notifications are cleared automatically after few second's in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying get push notifications when application is not working on background also. I have tried many solutions but not get notifications properly. I am tried fallowing solution for getting push notification's when application is not running on background. It receive the push notifications in lower android devices and that to it show's only few seconds in notification bar. Then after it automatically cleared. What the problem of getting notification when application is not running on the background. what the cause of clearing notifications automatically. Please suggest any idea.

### Sample code:

BroadcastReceiver :

```
  [assembly: Permission(Name = "@PACKAGE_NAME@.permission.C2D_MESSAGE")]
  [assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "@PACKAGE_NAME@.permission.C2D_MESSAGE")]
  [assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE")]

  //GET_ACCOUNTS is needed only for Android versions 4.0.3 and below
  [assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS")]
  [assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.INTERNET")]
  [assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK")]
  namespace SampleApp.Droid.PushNotificationHelper
  {
   [BroadcastReceiver(Permission = Gcm.Client.Constants.PERMISSION_GCM_INTENTS)]
   [IntentFilter(new string[] { Gcm.Client.Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_MESSAGE },
   Categories = new string[] { "@PACKAGE_NAME@" })]
   [IntentFilter(new string[] { Gcm.Client.Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_REGISTRATION_CALLBACK },
   Categories = new string[] { "@PACKAGE_NAME@" })]
   [IntentFilter(new string[] { Gcm.Client.Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_LIBRARY_RETRY },
   Categories = new string[] { "@PACKAGE_NAME@" })]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]

public class BroadcastReceiver : GcmBroadcastReceiverBase<PushHandlerService>
{
    public static string[] SENDER_IDS = new string[] { Constants.PushNotificationSenderId };

    public const string TAG = "MyBroadcastReceiver-GCM";

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnReceive(context, intent);

        var pm = PowerManager.FromContext(context);
        var wakeLock = pm.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial, "GCM Broadcast Reciever Tag");
        wakeLock.Acquire();

        RunningAppProcessInfo myProcess = new RunningAppProcessInfo();
        ActivityManager.GetMyMemoryState(myProcess);
        var isInForeground = myProcess.Importance != Importance.Foreground;

         if (isInForeground)
        {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(PushHandlerService));
            context.StartService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean get push notifications even if your application is working on background ?

Comment: Hi York, my requirement is getting push notifications, when application is not working on the background(when application kills from background) also need get push notifications. Generally we are receiving push notifications when application is running only.